# How to play mp4 audio file in android phone?

Tags: android, asp.net, html, audio, mp4

how can i play the mp4 audio file in web browser (html5 & asp.net) instead of using the music player of android phone itself ?

because i found that there are some android phone player will be black screen during play mp4 audio files. user may confused about it...

so i want to play the file embeded in web browser.

thanks.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

put this markup in your web page:

```
<audio src="yourfile.mp4" controls></audio>
```

see here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video